# Single Page Application Rest API Client

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, single-page-application, crud

I need to create an SPA for an API where the user can search for content within the API, the given API is the Victoria and Albert museum one. I've done a lot of research but I am struggling to make sense of what I am reading. I need to use HTML, CSS and Javascript with absolutely no frameworks or libraries. I dont suppose anyone knows of any example web pages similar to my task, or if you know of any articles/tutorials which can help me gain a better understanding of my task. I understand the concept of it but my javascript is weak which I think is what's holding me back.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are trying to fetch data from an API (which is already created) and you can not use a library (like jquery) is that right? Can you describe your page a little better?

Comment: Yes, the page is pretty much going to have a header, a search bar then an area for. the results to appear, and the results that are going to appear will be the names of the objects and then some other parts of the object as well, such as description.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I created an example that hopefully can help you. First of all this is the (pretty simple) html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AJAX Request</title>
    <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search-input">
    <span id="response-container" ></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Then we need our JS code to manipulate. Pay special attention on **fetchAPIData()** function since it is the core of your question. I commented the code since you are not used to JS (as you affirmed).

```
// First you need to "get" the object that is going emit
// events every time the user press a key 
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');
const responseContainer = document.getElementById('response-container');


// Here we attach to the search input an event so every time he
// presses a key on his keyboard we ask our api some data calling
// the fetchAPIData function
searchInput.addEventListener('keydown', updateSearchTerm);
// Using keyup event is a work around to ignore backspace key
// and other keys we don't want to have in our search term. I avoided to use
// REGEX here since it can be quite scary for beginners.
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', updateSearchTerm);

function updateSearchTerm(e) {
    const searchTerm = searchInput.value;
    if (e.type === 'keyup') {
        fetchAPIData(searchTerm);
    }
}

function fetchAPIData(searchTerm) {

    if(searchTerm === '') {
        return;
    }

    // I'm going to use PokeAPI just for the sake of example
    const APIURL = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${searchTerm}`;

    // fetch() is a JS built in function to deal with http requests for ya.
    // Although it deals with promises (kinda of an advanced topic)
    // we can make our code look very syncronous
    // using .then() function when http response is good and 
    // .catch() when http response is bad (in this case we just clean our response placeholder)
    fetch(APIURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseObject => {
        // responseObject['species']['name'] and responseObject['sprites']['front_default']
        // comes from our json response
        const pokemonName = responseObject['species']['name'];
        const pokemonFrontPicture = responseObject['sprites']['front_default'];

        responseContainer.innerHTML = `
            <p>${pokemonName}</p>
            <img src="${pokemonFrontPicture}" alt="${pokemonName} front sprite">
        `;
    }).catch(() => {
        responseContainer.innerHTML = `
            <p></p>
            <img>
        `;
    })
}
```

This is the final result (it calls the API and responds with the inputed pokemon info):

[image]

Hope it was helpful! :)